# Error while build ffmpeg for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ffmpeg

I'm trying to build fmmpeg for iOS with the following config:

`./configure --prefix=build/armv7 --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --enable-avutil --enable-avresample --enable-cross-compile --sysroot="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk" --target-os=darwin --cc=gcc  --extra-cflags="-arch armv7 -mfpu=neon -miphoneos-version-min=6.0" --extra-ldflags="-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=6.0" --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a9 --enable-pic`

when i try to make it i'm receiving the follow error:

`AS  libavcodec/arm/vc1dsp_neon.o
libavcodec/arm/vc1dsp_neon.S:751:10: error: unexpected token in argument list
  ra .dn d28.i8
         ^
libavcodec/arm/vc1dsp_neon.S:752:10: error: unexpected token in argument list
  rb .dn d29.i8
         ^
libavcodec/arm/vc1dsp_neon.S:753:10: error: unexpected token in argument list
  rc .dn d30.i8
         ^
libavcodec/arm/vc1dsp_neon.S:754:10: error: unexpected token in argument list
  rd .dn d31.i8
         ^
libavcodec/arm/vc1dsp_neon.S:757:14: error: invalid operand for instruction
        vmov ra, #4 
             ^
libavcodec/arm/vc1dsp_neon.S:758:14: error: invalid operand for instruction
        vmov rb, #53 
             ^
libavcodec/arm/vc1dsp_neon.S:759:14: error: invalid operand for instruction
        vmov rc, #18 
             ^
libavcodec/arm/vc1dsp_neon.S:760:14: error: invalid operand for instruction
        vmov rd, #3 
             ^
libavcodec/arm/vc1dsp_neon.S:864:10: error: unexpected token in argument list
  ra .dn d28.i16
         ^
libavcodec/arm/vc1dsp_neon.S:865:10: error: unexpected token in argument list
  rb .dn d29.i16
         ^`

what could be the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Errors compiling ffmpeg for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316852/errors-compiling-ffmpeg-for-iphone)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the flags `--disable-neon` and `--disable-armv5te`.

BTW, the following set of flags does the trick for AMRv7:

```
'--arch=arm',
'--enable-pic',
"--extra-cflags='-arch armv7 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0'",
"--extra-ldflags='-arch armv7 -miphoneos-version-min=6.0'",
'--disable-neon',
'--enable-optimizations',
'--disable-debug',
'--disable-armv5te',
'--disable-armv6',
'--disable-armv6t2',

'--disable-ffmpeg',
'--disable-ffplay',
'--disable-ffserver',
'--disable-ffprobe',
'--disable-doc',
'--disable-bzlib',
'--target-os=darwin',
'--enable-cross-compile',
'--enable-version3',
```

Or, event better, you change the version of gas-preprocessor you have to the libAV *maintained* version: https://github.com/libav/gas-preprocessor

Hope this helps.